# Postgres insert optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, bulkinsert

I have a script that generates tens of thousands of inserts into a postgres db through a custom ORM.  As you can imagine, it's quite slow.  This is used for development purposes in order to create dummy data.  Is there a simple optimization I can do at the Postgres level to make this faster?  It's the only script running, sequentially, and requires no thread safety.

Perhaps I can turn off all locking, safety checks, triggers, etc?  Just looking for a quick and dirty solution that will greatly speed up this process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need that kind of functionality in production environment, I'd suggest you turn fsync off from your PostgreSQL config. This will speed up the inserts dramatically.

Never turn off fsync on a production database.

Comment: I agree: fsync should never be turned off in production (unless you have a very reliable battery backed controller). But synchronous_commit = false might actually improve things and doesn't impose a big risk

Comment: In my test environment `synchronous_commit` did not improve speed enough to be of difference. IIRC this cut a 2 minute DB creation and population process to half, but turning off fsync made it run in 10 seconds. I don't have tens of thousands of records so my test database never hits the disc with `fsync=off`.

Comment: A battery backed cache can't save you from having fsync turned off!  If your OS crashes out OR loses power after having a fake fsync, before the data is written to a disk, you WILL lose data.    There are also questions about full page writes right now being 100% safe on even BBU caching RAID controllers.

Answer (score 8):

The fastest way to insert data would be the `COPY` command. 
But that requires a flat file as its input. I guess generating a flat file is not an option.

Don't commit too often, especially do *not* run this with autocommit enabled. 
"Tens of thousands" sounds like a single commit at the end would be just right.

If you can convice your ORM to make use of Postgres' multi-row insert that would speed up things as well

This is an example of a multi-row insert:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2) 
values 
(row_1_col_value1, row_1_col_value_2), 
(row_2_col_value1, row_2_col_value_2), 
(row_3_col_value1, row_3_col_value_2)
```

If you can't generate the above syntax and you are using Java make sure you are using batched statements instead of single statement inserts (maybe other DB layers allow something similar)

Edit:

jmz' post inspired me to add something:

You might also see an improvement when you increase `wal_buffers` to some bigger value (e.g. 8MB) and `checkpoint_segments` (e.g. 16)

Comment: The copy command does NOT require a flat file, as it can take input from standard in.  Make a plaintext backup of your db and you'll see it full of copy commands involving stdin.

Comment: @Scott: you are right. But the format is still a "plain text" format. So in order to take advantage of the fast COPY mechanism, the effort to rewrite the existing program is essentially the same whether COPY takes it input from a file or from stdin

Answer (score 6):

For inserts that number in the hundreds to thousands, batch them:

```
begin;
insert1 ...
insert2 ...
...
insert10k ... 
commit;
```

For inserts in the millions use copy:

```
COPY test (ts) FROM stdin;
2010-11-29 22:32:01.383741-07
2010-11-29 22:32:01.737722-07
... 1Million rows
\.
```

Make sure any col used as an fk in another table is indexed if it's more than trivial in size in the other table.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is remove all indexs, do your inserts, and then recreate the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sending a batch of tens of thousands of INSERTs **OR** are you sending tens of thousands of INSERTs?

I know with Hibernate you can batch all your SQL statements up and send them at the end in one big chunk instead of taking the tax of network and database overhead of making thousands of SQL statements individually.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just initializing constant test data, you could also put the test data into a staging table(s), then just copy the table contents, using

```
INSERT INTO... SELECT...
```

that should be about as fast as using COPY (though I did not benchmark it), with the advantage that you can copy using just SQL commands, without the hassle of setting up an external file like for COPY.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do as much as possible in one request!

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2) 
values (
  unnest(array[row_1_col_value_1, row_2_col_value_1, row3_col_value_1]), 
  unnest(array[row_1_col_value_2, row_2_col_value_2, row_3_col_value_2));
```

This resembles the suggestion of @a_horse_with_no_name. The advantage of using `unnest` is: You can use query parameters that contain arrays!

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2) 
values (unnest(:col_values_1), unnest(:col_values_2));
```

By collapsing three `insert` statements into one, you save more than 50% of execution time.
And by using query parameters with 2000 values in a single `Insert`, I get a speed factor of 150 in my application.